# Infinite binary sequences countable set

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, binary

I know that the set of all binary sequences is uncountable, and I'm asked to prove that the set of all binary sequences that are constant from a certain point ($n\in\mathbb{N}$) is countable, meaning the set:
$\{\eta:\eta\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\land\exists n\in\mathbb{N}\forall m>n(\eta(m)=\eta(n))\}$
is countable. 
How does the fact that all binary sequences in this set are constant from a certain point make it countable?

Comment: You could list them as follows:  $0\overline0,0\overline1,1\overline0,1\overline1,10\overline0,10\overline1,11\overline0,11\overline1,100\overline0,100\overline1,101\overline0,101\overline1,110\overline0,110\overline1,111\overline0,111\overline1,...$; the list would have duplicates, but that's okay

Answer (score 3):

HINT: For each $n$, the set of binary sequences that are constant from the $n$-th term on is finite; you should be able to write down its actual cardinality without much trouble.

Comment: Can I look at $\{\eta\}$ as an infinite union of finite sets (each set in the size of $2^n$?

Comment: @GalBenAyun: So you don’t yet have the theorem that the union of countably many countable sets is countable?

Comment: I think the word that I was missing was union of countably many countable sets. It's countable because each subset in the union is determined uniquely by a natural number?

Comment: @GalBenAyun: Yes: for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ you have a finite (hence countable) set of sequences that are constant from the $n$-th term on, and $\Bbb Z^+$ is countable.

Answer (score 0):

Assume, 
$E_n$ be the collection of binary sequences which are constant after nth stage. $|E_n| < 2^n \  \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $.
and 
$X$ the collection of all the binary sequences which are constant after some stage. 
Then, $X \subseteq \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E_n$  which is countable union of finite sets, hence, countable.

Answer (score 0):

If $\eta$ has the binary number $b$ followed a string of all zeroes starting with the $n^{th}$, map $\eta$ to $2b\in\mathbb N$;

if $\eta$ has the binary number $b$ followed by a string of all ones starting with the $n^{th}$,

map $\eta$ to $2b+1\in\mathbb N$.

This is an injective function from to $\{\eta\}$ to $\mathbb N$, so $\{\eta\}$ is countable.